# I need some help for checkbox php

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

i'm new here and i need some help plz if you could give me a solution to my problem it will be great.So i need some help to resolve this probleme, here HTML

`<html><body>
    <form method="post" action="test.php">
    Flights on: <br/>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Daily">Daily<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Sunday">Sunday<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Monday">Monday<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Tuesday">Tuesday <br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Wednesday">Wednesday<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Thursday">Thursday <br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Friday">Friday<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Saturday">Saturday <br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
     </form>
     </body>
     </html>`

AND the PHP one :

`

```
 // Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());

$checkBox = implode(',', $_POST['Days']);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{       
$query="INSERT INTO test (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7) VALUES (" . $_POST['Days'][0] . ",
"  .   $_POST['Days'][1] . ",
" . $_POST['Days'][2] . ",
" . $_POST['Days'][3] . ",
" . $_POST['Days'][4] . ",
" . $_POST['Days'][5] . ",
" . $_POST['Days'][6] . ",
"  .$_POST['Days'][7] . ")";     

mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error() );

echo "Complete";

}

?>`
```

it's says to me undifined offsets and :You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',,,,)' at line 1
plzzzzz HELP!!!!
i need to insert the values of the checkbox checked into my sql db.

Comment: You have defined 7 columns but 8 values in your query.

Comment: Did you try reading through Stack Overflow questions regarding checkboxes and database interaction?  There are a lot of them!  Also, don't use mysql_*, it's deprecated, hasn't been maintained for years, isn't really compatible with Mysql 5 and will be removed entirely from future versions of PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
echo "INSERT INTO test (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7) VALUES ('".implode("','", $_POST[Days])."')";
```

***output:***

```
INSERT INTO test (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7) VALUES ('Daily','Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the checkbox is not checked it will not be posted. You can add custom keys for your checkboxes like this Days[Daily] and then check if the value is set using php:

```
$daly = empty($_POST['Days']['Daily']) ? 0 : $_POST['Days']['Daily'];
```

You should do the same thing with all checkboxes.

Comment: alternatively, you may want to supply a 'hidden' value for unchecked checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Reason:
The unselected checkbox will not be posted.
For instance, if you didn't select checkbox7 then `$_POST['Days'][7]` will be empty , your query will end with ',,)'. Like this:

```
INSERT INTO test (c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7) VALUES (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,,)
```

And also, your columns should math your fileds.

Change your query logic to something like this will work:

```
$query="INSERT INTO test (c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7) VALUES ('" . $_POST['Days'][0] . "',
'"  .   $_POST['Days'][1] . "',
'" . $_POST['Days'][2] . "',
'" . $_POST['Days'][3] . "',
'" . $_POST['Days'][4] . "',
'" . $_POST['Days'][5] . "',
'" . $_POST['Days'][6] . "',
'"  .$_POST['Days'][7] . "')";
```

It will produce

```
INSERT INTO test (c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7) VALUES ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out to learn how to connect to mysql. http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_connect.asp

I would recommend that before jumping straight into PHP, you should learn the basics and then start to build out your own PHP project.

Also, always look at the error given, it says that the error is on line one of your PHP code, so you should check that out to find out the problem.

Here are some of the best places to learn code...

http://www.codecademy.com/ and http://www.phptherightway.com/

The first one is interactive and is probably the most useful to get you started. Then check out PHP the right way as this will show you how to make PHP project the right and most up to date way.

Good luck on your future PHP projects. :)

Comment: tut, tut, tut http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Comment: Sorry *bows head in shame*. W3schools although not always correct is always number one so it's too easy to link to. :( Do I not get plus points for Codecadamy and PHP the right way? :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think you need to change your php. You need to store it in the variables. Please check this code and tell me it is working or not.And you need to add one more - c8

```
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());

$checkBox = implode(',', $_POST['Days']);
 $days1=$_POST['Days'][0];
$days2=$_POST['Days'][1] ;
$days3=$_POST['Days'][2] ;
$days4=$_POST['Days'][3] ;
$days5=$_POST['Days'][4] ;
$days6=$_POST['Days'][5] ;
$days7=$_POST['Days'][6] ;
$days8=$_POST['Days'][7] ;
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{       
$query="INSERT INTO test (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8) VALUES ('$days1',
'$days1','$days2','$days3','$days4','$days5','$days6','$days7','$days8');     

mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error() );

echo "Complete";

}

?>
```

Comment: " is missing in the end of the query, and ';'is missing for $days1 rther than that the insertion worked but not like it supposed to be.I want to insert like if i choose monday it insert it in c2 and if i choose sunday it insert it in c8 ,if i choose monday,friday it will insert monday in c2 and friday in c6...

Answer (score 0):

Error is here: `$checkBox = implode(',', $_POST['Days']);`

**the `','` part -** you should use `"','"` instead of `','` because sql needs each values within single quote marks.

and here: `VALUES (" . $_POST['Days'][0] . ", .... , "  .$_POST['Days'][7] . ")";`

you are missing **starting single quote mark for first value and ending single quote mark for final value**. so add extra single quote mark after open the bracket and before ending the bracket:

`VALUES ('" . $_POST['Days'][0] . ", .... , "  .$_POST['Days'][7] . "')";`

***And use mysqli_ with prepared statements and don't use mysql_ when dealing with database since it will be deprecated soon. and for a better security.**